# Show that each $I_n = \left( \frac{1}{2n}, \frac{1}{n} \right) $ is open, $n \in \mathbb{N} $

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

Show that each $I_n = \left( \frac{1}{2n}, \frac{1}{n} \right) $ is  an open set for all $n \in \mathbb{N} $

I was thinking if it is sufficient to use the fact that those sets has supremum and infimum and for all $a \in I_n $ we take $2 \epsilon =\min${$d(a, supI_n), d(a, infI_n)$} (i.e, d is distance as defined usually in $\mathbb{R}$ and epsilon is the half of the minimum of distances) to show that $B_{\epsilon}(a) \in I_n$

Thanks !

Comment: Sounds good. You don't really need to use $\inf$ and $\sup$ here though - just take $1/2n$ and $1/n$ which you know must be the infimum/supremum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any point $x\in (\frac{1}{2n},\frac{1}{n})$, choose $r=min(x-\frac{1}{2n},\frac{1}{n}-x)$

Answer (score 1):

Try this hint: $I_n = \dfrac1n I_1$ and so it is enough to prove that $I_1=(\dfrac12, 1)$ is open because $I_n$ is the same as $I_1$ with all distances scaled down.